# Bottom margin in html

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make a html page for embeding into a iframe.

But even when i set all borders, margins and paddings off. And the video is only 560 x 315 PX.
When i make my iframe the same size, it gets scrollbars. It happens only for the up/down scrollbar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your `#container_wrapper` element to remove the scrollbars.

Comment: This was the trick!
I can't add CSS to the embeded page because it isnt my page ;) thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

use 'overflow: hidden' on the iframe CSS on the page where it is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CSS for this. There is an attribute built into the iFrame specially for this.

Turn scrolling off using the scrolling attribute in the iFrame

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://your_site/" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

Setting `overflow: hidden` on the iFrame won't actually work. Has anyone actually tried it?

Comment: That works as well! Thanks! Could you delete my dev url in the post? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add overflow:hidden on to your iframe.

```
iframe {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If there is a scroll hiding it is not a solution.

Comment: @gipsydipsydoo - Just turn scrolling="no" on in the iFrame. You don't need to do any CSS at all.

Comment: If there is a scroll it shows that the size of the iframe is smaller then its content or bigger then parent's size. The video will not be fully visible. Your method is not the best one.